# How to use StanfordNLP Python package to do dependency parsing?

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use the new NN-based parser at [here](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanfordnlp) to find all adjective phrases in a sentence (e.g., `good` and `extremely good` in `The weather is extremely good`), however, it's very lack of documentation and I could not get it working. My current code is

```
import stanfordnlp
nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline()
doc = nlp("The weather is extremely good")
doc.sentences[0].print_dependencies()
```

which gives me

```
('The', '2', 'det')
('weather', '5', 'nsubj')
('is', '5', 'cop')
('extremely', '5', 'advmod')
('good', '0', 'root')
```

But it is not clear how to extract the information I need, as this does not seem to be a tree structure. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time there is not Python support for constituency parses which is what you want.  This is just returning the dependency parses (a different type of parse).

You can use `stanfordnlp` to communicate with a Java server and get constituency parses in that manner.

There is example code here for accessing the constituency parses:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/corenlp_client.html

Comment: thank you for the reply. However, how can we interpret the output above? I also must work with that dependency parser, and I have the same problem. How to interpret/process that output? Moreover, would it make sense to feed those dependency raw data information into an LSTM language model?

Answer (score 0):

The numerical index of each word specified in the output indicates the index of the governor word (head of that word).

For example, the word `"Whether"` is a child of the word `"Good"` (with the index of 5 because `"Good"` is the fifth word in the actual sentence), so it takes its governor's (head) index which in here is 5 (`"Good"`).

You, can get the dependency structure representation from  `<http://corenlp.run/>` and compare it with the representation based on my description for better clarification.